# Did LEGO ever make motorised boats?

Tags: motor, water, boat

Did LEGO ever make motorised boats? Or an official motor that could be attached to LEGO floating boats.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

LEGO had a "Accessory Motor for Boats" included in small number of boats/sets but also released as [Accessory Motor for Boats polybag (7099)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7099-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) add-on.

Sets that included the motor in [Orange](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=48083c02&in=S) are 7906 and 7899 and in [Yellow](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=48083c01&in=S) are 7244, 4669 and 7099 mentioned above.

[image]

And here's a picture from Turbo-charged Police Boat (4669) set's instructions showing how to attach and operate the motor.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The Lego police boat ([set 4010](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4020-1), from 1987) had a notch for fitting a motor on the bottom of the hull and it was referenced in [its instructions](https://lego.brickinstructions.com/en/lego_instructions/set/4010/Police_Rescue_Boat):

[image: Instructions for set 4010]

The instructions read, in several languages:

> In some countries propellor motors (not made by LEGO™) are available from model shops. The notch in the bottom of the hull allows these motors to be attached.

There are other boats with similar hulls: sets 4011, 4012, 4020, 4021, 4022, 4030, 4031.

According to https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/156353-boat-hull-motors/ , the notch is compatible with the Playmobil 5159 Submarine Motor:

[image: playmobil motor]

Comment: I think all the boat sets from that era with a single-piece hull had the notch for a Playmobil motor.

Comment: @Mark I have several boats from that era that all have the mount point.  I figured it was for a motor but I have never actually seen one!